# Restrict user script execution

Tags: linux, security, python, jails, sandbox

I have a game engine running on a Debian server. The game involves bots, which are coded in Python by the players.

1. A player write a bot in Python
2. Upon validation, the code is sent to the server
3. A Python script execute the code

The bot's script is a regular Python script, so players can do whatever they want in it. I want the player to be able to import modules, but not to break the server (i.e. scanning the server file system, deleting files, *or worse*).

How can I ensure that the script does not break the system, knowing that:

- The script must be able to communicates in TCP/IP to the game engine (localhost)
- I want to allow the players to import any standard Python module
- Later the game will support other scripting languages (Ruby, Perl, Lua, JS…)

I suspect that a way whould be to play with users and groups. Another could be something similar to FreeBSD jails. I am not familiar with any of these methods.

Comment: you could give them a [docker](https://www.docker.com/) environment to run in. they are easy to set up running a minimal debian, and are lighter than a VM.

Comment: Do the scripts all execute as the same user? If so, hopefully not root. If so, can't you just make do with creating users for each player, and setting default user/group rights appropriately? Then a script by a normal user can not delete stuff in e.g. /etc. Set some resource utilization limits too, so that an individual cannot bring your game server to its knees.

Comment: I can indeed add accounts specifically dedicated to script execution. I suspected that setting up the correct permissions for users/groups could solve the problem (at least a major part). As mentioned in the question, I just don't know what to do exactly, and how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be done with [chroot](https://wiki.debian.org/chroot) or maybe even [lxc](https://wiki.debian.org/LXC) in debian.

EDIT:
You may want to use overlayfs or squashfs to make what you're doing faster(instantaneous). For that you need debootstrap and squashfs-tools.

With these tools you'll able to give your users different runtime versions or archituctures to choose from.  For that You need `qemu-user-static` and `ChrootDebootstrap`.

Comment: chroot **with a dedicated user** (who doesn't run any process outside the chroot) provides filesystem isolation, but still allows escapes such as networking.

Comment: @Gilles He said he wants networking. And I think those escapes can be taken care of with iptables --gid-owner or something.

Comment: That's what I feared, that the player would be able to launch (for instance) a server for the time of the execution.
Anyway, thank for your answer, I have no time to investigate on it right now, but this time will come.